# Devolver los porcentajes de los valores de una numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Suponiendo que yo tengo una numpy array con x valores dentro,como puedo conseguir que me devuelva el porcentaje de los valores.

````
a=([-2, -1,  0, -2,  0, -2,  0, -2,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,
       -1,  0, -1,  0,  0, -1, -1,  0, -1, -2,  0, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1,
       -2, -2,  0,  0, -1, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0, -2,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,
        0,  0, -2,  0,  0, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0, -2,  0,  0,  0, -1, -2,  0,
        0, -2, -2,  0,  0, -1,  0, -2,  0,  0, -2,  0, -1, -2,  0, -2, -1,
        0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1, -1,  0, -2, -2, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0])
for n in a:
    twos=0*100
    ones=0*100
    zeros=0*100
    if n == -2:
        twos+=1
    if n == -1:
        ones+=1
    if n == 0:
        zeros+=1
print(twos,ones,zeros)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por supuestos que puede hacerse. **Hay muchísimas formas de hacerlo**, la que más utilizo yo es esta:

1. Me traigo `Counter` de la biblioteca de Python `collections`. Esta función es un **diccionario avanzado**, que por cada número que se encuentra, si es nuevo lo almacena y le pone un uno como valor, si ya existe le va sumando valores.
2. Después **extraigo cada clave valor con el método** `.items()` que tiene cualquier diccionario y hago que devuelva el porcentaje.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter



a = np.array([-2, -1,  0, -2,  0, -2,  0, -2,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,
       -1,  0, -1,  0,  0, -1, -1,  0, -1, -2,  0, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1,
       -2, -2,  0,  0, -1, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0, -2,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,
        0,  0, -2,  0,  0, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0, -2,  0,  0,  0, -1, -2,  0,
        0, -2, -2,  0,  0, -1,  0, -2,  0,  0, -2,  0, -1, -2,  0, -2, -1,
        0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1, -1,  0, -2, -2, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0])


counter = Counter(a)

size = a.size

for k, v in counter.items():
    print(k,'->', int(v/size*100), '%')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Cuando uso tu código me devuelve un nameerror, name collections is not defined

Comment: Perdón @L.Bar5522 copie mal el código. El problema es que había llamado a ```Counter``` mal. ya he editado la pregunta y lo he corregido

Comment: No pasa nada he importado collections y ya funcionaba el código muchísimas gracias